# Regional subdomains

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to make some regional subdomains of my current `site.com` - something like `city1.site.com` and `city2.site.com`, but I don't want to copy all the files from original domain to subdomain.
Is it possible to show on subdomain `city1.site.com` the same info as on `site.com` but just set one variable, something like `$city = 123`? With this variable on `city1.site.com` I can show more specific contacts and products for this city.

I'm new to subdomain so please help, my site is on PHP & MySQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have few regions, you can manually create subdomains for each region and point the domains to the same folder as your main site. Then in your script you grab the host and match it to regions and assign desired value to a variable.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'city1.site.com') {
  $city = 123;
} else if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'city2.site.com') {
  $city = 223;
}
```

If you have many regions and want a dynamic match, you can match any subdomain to your main site path and inside the script you can use a method to get the subdomain and search in your database. Example:

```
<?php
 $subdomain = strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], '.', true);
 $city = getRegion($subdomain);
 if(!$city) {
 // throw 404 error
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  exit;
}
// getRegion($subdomain) is a method that should search your database to match the subdomain to a region
```

To match all subdomains to a path you need to use wildcard in CPanel. See tutorial: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-to-create-a-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel

Comment: Thank you fo tutorial, but what about unwanted subdomains like nothing.site.com? How prevent them to show, especially not to be scanned by Google?

Comment: If you have a city that does not exists, throw a 404 error to tell google that page does not exists. 
You need to make sitemap.xml files to tell google what to index.

Comment: Ok, I think 404 will do it! Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code with an example for you on what error to throw

Comment: Thanks! And what to do if I want to have wildcard subdomains and one fo testing, for example test.site.com with its own directory?

Comment: Create the subdomain manually. Wildcard is only for non-existing subdomains

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the `$_SERVER` superglobals in php (read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php especially the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`) to find out, which subdomain is the current one (if any)

The rest is probably easy, for example a switch statement depending on the current subdomain like

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'city1.site.com': $abc=1; break;
  case 'city2.site.com': $abc=2; break;
  default: $abc=0; break;
}
```

**update:** the idea is, to use the same code for all subdomains (you don't want to maintain an arbitrary amount of copies) and force different behaviour through code. perhaps you can even setup a "catchall" domain somehow.

So, if you setup your domain `site.com` to live in your server's `htdocs/site.com` directory, use the *same directory* for all the other domains as well.

To achieve different outputs for your sites, you then check the `$abc` variable or some other var (perhaps even `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`) to do

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.site.com') !== FALSE) {
  $subdomain = str_replace('.site.com','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
else {
  $subdomain = null;
}
// now 'city1' is in $subdomain
```

After you have extracted the subdomain, you can run sql queries or the like with that value (if your database is setup appropriately).

Comment: Thanks! And how do I get all contents of site.com on city1.site.com? With .htaccess?

Comment: that code is under the assumption you have the exact same files. (meaning, not even a copy but literally the same document root for all domains)

Comment: Yeah! But what rules I need in htaccess or maybe server config files to show files from site.com on my subdomains?

Comment: So you're saying you don't know how to setup your multiple domains?

Comment: To setup subdomains, check my edited answer above. You se how to make all subdomains to work. You don't need .htaccess rules

Comment: The tutorial says in the first paragraph: _Wildcard subdomain allows you to point **all non-existing subdomains** to a specific folder in your account. It means that if you enter **different subdomains (which are not created in your cPanel) in your browser, they all will show the same content that you uploaded to the folder set** for the wildcard subdomain._
You will create your subdomain for test manually.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to make sure your DNS records are ready. Add an A record for the following if it doesn't already exist.

**EDIT** - If you are using a shared host, this might not work properly **END**

Set the name part to '*' and then the next to value to the server IP address you currently use. Once this rule is in place, people can go to {anything}.site.com and will all be sent to the same server.

At this point, I would do something similar to Jakumi's answer but keep it simpler

```
/* Cut up the URL */
$hostDetails = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
/* Get the first part (city) of the URL */
$city = current($hostDetails);
/* Default check */
if($city == 'site') { $city = 'YOUR_DEFAULT'; }
```

Comment: I like this way! But what to do in case they type non-existing city or whatever like nothing.site.com? How to filter such subdomains in order to prevent Google to scan it?

Comment: For your first question, you'd have to do a check against something (DB record?) and then default if improper or use Jakumi's answer. For the second part, I don't think you'd have to worry about Google scanning non-existant sub-domains unless they are "hit". If this were the case, you could use the Webmaster Tools and define the subdomains, that way you could remove them